# Display: inline-block and center aligning

Tags: html, css

```
#words { width: 600px; height: 450px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; border: 1px solid black; }
#words li { display: inline-block; width: auto; padding: 10px; height: auto; background-color: #c4c4c4; margin: 2px; text-align: center; }
```

So that's my CSS code for my mark-up:

```
<ul id="words">
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah</li>
</ul>
```

But, I cannot seem to have `width:auto;` on the `<li>` without floating them left (in FireFox).

Any ideas?

Comment: Those blocks still float left.

Comment: @Neurofluxation: He simply made a jsFiddle demo of your given code so we don't have to.

Comment: Ok - thanks.. but maybe he should have stated that

Comment: @Neurofluxation: Maybe, but I'd hope you would recognize your *own code* :)

Comment: @Neurofluxation: What is the desired result here?

Comment: I would like all the boxes stacked up, center aligned, with extra padding and margins - am I going the wrong way about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I sorted it.

`#words` now has `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it stacked up vertically (as I understand) then you just need to remove "inline-" from your `words li` selector:

```
#words li 
{ 
    display: block;
...
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/EWZLq/2/).

Comment: I also thought it might be this, but it seems too easy.. :S

Comment: I guess I totally misunderstood the question. Added the solution to teh jsfiddle and still don't get what the OP wanted :D
http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/EWZLq/3/

Comment: Bloody StackOverflow isn't saving my comments! Horizontally please. But I fixed it now anyway (see my answer)